# Como conseguir o valor de um botão utilizando o $_REQUEST?

Tags: php

Boa noite.
Eu faço uma query, carrego os dados para uma tabela e em cada linha eu tenho um botão que a cada registo irá ter um valor diferente.
A minha questão é como pegar, em php, o valor do botão selecionado utilizando o $_REQUEST. O valor que eu consigo ecoar é sempre o valor do primeiro botão. Como se faz isto com o $_REQUEST? Também aceito outras sugestões!

Este é o meu botão

```
<button type="button" name="ver_ee" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3" style="background-color: Transparent; border: none;" value=' . $registos[0] . '><i class="fa fa-male"></i></button>
```

Este é o codigo para ecoar o valor do botão

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                                <h2 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Encarregado de educação</h2>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                <?php
                                                    $a = $_REQUEST["ver_ee"];
                                                    echo $a;
                                                ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>-->
                                                <input type='button' data-dismiss="modal" name='cancelar' class="btn" value='Fechar' /> 
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Veja se este exemplo ajuda você:**

Crie um arquivo teste.php e coloque na sua hospedagem, no exemplo abaixo utilizei localhost, você pode mudar se quiser:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Exemplo Simples</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <?php

        if(isset($_REQUEST['id']) && isset($_REQUEST['titulo'])){
            $result =  '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">';
            $result .= "Você está editando o registro com ID ". $_REQUEST['id'] . " e com o título " . $_REQUEST['titulo'];
            $result .= '</div>';
            echo $result;
        }
        ?>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Titulo</th>
                    <th>Editar</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Primeiro titulo</td>
                    <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="/teste.php?id=1&titulo=Primeiro titulo" role="button">Editar</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Segundo titulo</td>
                    <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="/teste.php?id=2&titulo=Segundo titulo" role="button">Editar</a></td>
                </tr
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: valeu mano!!!! É nois

Comment: @TiagoSimoes [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/99718)